# Continuous bijective mapping between $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}^*$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, continuity

Is there a continuous bijective mapping from $\mathbb{C}$  to   $\mathbb{C}^* = \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$?

Comment: ... where $\mathbb C^*$ is ...?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}^*=\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$

Answer (score -3):

Hint: one  is [simply connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space), the other is not.

EDIT: Why in the world was this answer deleted?

EDIT: Suppose $f$ is such a map.  Let $x \in \mathbb C$, and $V$ a closed disk centred at $x$.  Since $V$ is compact, $f$ is a homeomorphism of $V$ onto $f(V)$.  The image of the interior of $V$ is a subset of $\mathbb C^*$ homeomorphic to an open disk and containing $f(x)$, so it is a neighbourhood of $f(x)$.  Thus $f$ is actually a homeomorphism of $\mathbb C$ onto $\mathbb C^*$.

Comment: The  image, by  a  continuous function, of   a  simply  connected domain  is  not  necesserely  simply  connected

Comment: Well, I voted to undelete, but @Joseph is correct. For example, there is a continuous bijective mapping from $[0,1)$ to $S^1$, and the former is simply connected but the latter is not.